# Ada select multiple entries

Tags: task, ada

I'm looking for a way to select on multiple entries. I've got the following task and select block. The intention is to run multiple (2) tasks elsewhere, run until one completes, or timeout after some amount of time

```
task type t_startup_task is
   entry start;
   entry started;
end t_startup_task;

task body t_startup_task is
   startup_sig : Boolean := False;
begin
   accept start;
   busy : loop -- wait for external flag to become true
      status.read_signal (startup_sig);
      if startup_sig then
         exit busy;
      end if;
      delay 0.1;
   end loop busy;
   accept started;
end t_startup_task;

<...>

startup_task.start;
select
   startup_task.started;
or
   state.wait_done; -- other entry
   abort startup_task;
   return False;
or
   delay 4.0;
end select;
```

However, this results in the following compile error:

```
only allowed alternative in timed entry call is delay
"or" not allowed here
```

What's the best way of actually doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use a `select` statement for deciding between multiple entry calls. You can however use them to decide between accepting entries, so an implementation with three tasks should work.

You can still have your return value by using an out parameter on the final entry call.

```
task startup_task is
    entry start;
    entry wait_done;
    entry signalled;
    entry started (success : out boolean);
end startup_task;

-- This task waits upon your other entry, then calls the startup_task
-- entry once it has completed
task startup_wait is
    entry start;
end startup_wait;
task body startup_wait is
begin
    accept start;
    state.wait_done;
    startup_task.wait_done;
end startup_wait;

-- This task contains your busy loop and calls the startup_task
-- entry once it has completed
task startup_signal is
    entry start;
end startup_signal;
task body startup_signal is
begin
    accept start;
    busy : loop -- wait for external flag to become true
        status.read_signal (startup_sig);
        if startup_sig then
            exit busy;
        end if;
        delay 0.1;
    end loop busy;
    startup_task.signalled;
end startup_signal;

-- This task provides the functionality of your invalid select statement, 
task body startup_task is
    success : boolean := False;
begin
    -- These start signals ensure that the subtasks wait for synchronisation
    accept start;
    startup_wait.start;
    startup_signal.start;
    select
        accept signalled;
        abort startup_wait;
        success := True;
    or
        accept wait_done;
        abort startup_signal;
    or
        delay 4.0
        abort startup_wait;
        abort startup_signal;
    end select;
    accept started (success);
end startup_task;

<...>

result : boolean;
begin
    -- this block replaces your invalid select statement
    startup_task.start;
    startup_task.started(result);
    return result;
end;
```

Note, I have not tested or compiled this code, but it should give an idea towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the language allows this:

```
select
   delay 4.0;
   ...
then abort
   select
      Entry1;
      ...
   then abort
      Entry2;
      ...
   end select;
end select;
```

which might do what you want. However, the best way is probably to have the tasks check in with a protected object, and wait on an entry of the PO:

```
protected Multi_Wait is
   procedure Task1_Ready;
   procedure Task2_Ready;
   entry Wait_For_Either (Task_1 : out Boolean; Task_2 : out Boolean);
private -- Multi_Wait
   Task1 : Boolean := False;
   Task2 : Boolean := False;
end Multi_Wait;
```

Then your code can do

```
select
   Multi_Wait.Wait_For_Either (Task_1 => Task_1, Task_2 => Task_2);

   if not Task_1 and Task_2 then
      abort T1;

      return False;
   end if;
or
   delay 4.0;
end select;
```

Your tasks call the appropriate procedure instead of waiting for a 2nd entry call.